# Why is "__proto__" hidden by default but not with JSON.parse() and how to show it in JSON.stringify()?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to pass an object to another module; My object includes `{__proto__: { value: 1}}`.

```
const x = {
  __proto__: { value: 1 }
}

console.log(x)
```

what I expected as a result was

`{__proto__: { value: 1 }}`

but what I got was

`{}`

and I did try using `"__proto__"`.

The only way I got it to work was by using

`JSON.parse("{\"__proto__\": { \"value\": 1 }}")`

but I really don't think this is very performant solution (would require a lot of code configuring)

Is there a method to get it to be read like the parse and have

`JSON.stringify(x)` result in `'{"__proto__": { "value": 1 }}'` not `'{}'`

Comment: Is `__proto__` here the same as [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)? If it is, in the name of "_performant solution_" it's better to forget such a fork, and make the object properly inherit from another object or create it using a class (or constructor).

Comment: @Teemu I am trying to simulate a `__proto__` injection, for that I need to send the __obj__ I have as a string like `?request=[{\"__proto__\":{\"value\": 1}]` but it never shows even in `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Do you really want to *log* an object and check if it logs `__proto__` or do you want to check `__proto__`? Because the latter doesn't necessarily rely on logging the whole object. You might do something like `Object.getPrototypeOf(x) === Object.prototype` which would more directly tell you whether the prototype is different from the default for plain objects.

Comment: @VLAZ I want to pass `{__proto__: { value: 1 }}` into `JSON.stringify(x)` and have the result be `'{"__proto__": { "value": 1 }}'` and not `'{}'`

Comment: And I'm asking if this is the real end goal or if that's just one possible way to get there and you've not considered asking about the real problem.

Comment: @VLAZ I haven't asked about the `JSON.stringify(x)` , that my problem, yes; will update it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`__proto__` key in object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#prototype_setter) is treated specially and initialises the internal *[[prototype]]* of the new object. It does no matter whether you write `{__proto__: …}` or `{"__proto__": …}` for that. (This is related - by name only - to the [`Object.prototype.__proto__` getter/setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto), but it is a separate and non-deprecated feature of object literals).

To create a normal own property with the literal name `__proto__`, you can use a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names):

```js
const x = {
  ["__proto__"]: { value: 1 }
};

console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Certainly a very hacky solution but you could define custom [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)  logic using the [`replace?`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#the_replacer_parameter) parameter. If a key of `x` is an empty string you can include the `__proto__` manually.

```js
const x = {
  test: "test",
  __proto__: {value: 1}
};

const result = JSON.stringify(x, (key, value) =>
  !key ? {["__proto__"]: x.__proto__, ...value} : value
);

console.log(result);
const parsed = JSON.parse(result);
console.log(parsed);
```